# Handle Matrix with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a file with linked data each two columns ( in this example is just 3, but could be more), in a tab delimited file:

```
Names   SampleA   Names   SampleB   Names   SamplesC
Name1      5      Name3      7      Name1         8
Name2      9      Name2      1      Name2         2
Name4      4      Name4      8      Name3         8
                                    NameX         10
```

And so on, what I want is to have a single column with the columns Names with not redundant data (Names), and in this case 3 columns with samples; in those samples that are not values for x name will be fill with 0:

```
Names     SampleA     SampleB    SampleC
Name1         5           0        8
Name2         9           1        2
Name3         0           7        8
Name4         4           8        0
NameX         0           0        10
```

How can I approach this matrix with pandas ???, I jus have tried with R and Perl, but I think will be easer with python using Pandas, I think it will be the best way to solve !!!

Thanks so much !!!!

Comment: I don't see how this question is marked *too broad*.

Comment: Read *too broad* as *no attempt*. If you go through the [tour of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, you will see there that you should provide details on what you tried before posting a question. You provided nothing and just asking us to write a code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try concat by group of two columns and sum:

```
new_df = pd.concat((df.iloc[:, i:i+2]
                      .set_index('Names')
                      .dropna(how='all') 
                    for i in range(0,len(df.columns),2)),
                   sort=False)
new_df.sum(level=0)
```

Output (you can reset index if you want):

```
    SampleA     SampleB     SampleC
Names           
Name1   5.0     0.0     8.0
Name2   9.0     1.0     2.0
Name4   4.0     8.0     0.0
Name3   0.0     7.0     8.0
NameX   0.0     0.0     10.0
```